# Property not defined error But it is defined Vue js Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have defined the function in my vue js file but it is giving me error for nameWithLang() function Please have a look

My Form

```
<multiselect v-model="selected" track-by="id" label="name" :options="options" :loading="isLoading" :internal-search="false" @search-change="getData" :multiple="true" :close-on-select="false" :hide-selected="true":internal-search="false" name="books[]" :show-labels="false" :custom-label="nameWithLang"></multiselect>
```

My vue js file

```
import AppForm from '../app-components/Form/AppForm';

Vue.component('coupon-form', {
    mixins: [AppForm],
    data: function() {
        return {
            form: {
                name:  '' ,
                description:  '' ,
                valid_from:  '' ,
                valid_till:  '' ,
                discount:  '' ,
                enabled:  false,
                books: [],
            },
            isLoading: false,
            options: [],
            selected: [],

        }
    },
    methods: {
        nameWithLang({ name, sku }) {
          return `${name} — ${sku}`
        },
        getData(query){
            this.isLoading = true;

            axios.post('/admin/books/find/'+query)
            .then((response) => {
                this.options = response.data;
                this.isLoading = false;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.isLoading = false;
            });
        },
    },
    watch: {
        selected (newValues) {
             this.form.books = newValues.map(obj => obj.id)
        }
    }
});
```

Other properties and functions are working nameWithLang is not working
It gives me error this

```
Property or method "nameWithLang" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.
```

Comment: Please can you show the markup for the form so that we can see the `multiselect` component being used in context. Also, I'm I correct in assuming you're using `inline-template` for your `coupon-form`?

Comment: `:custom-label="nameWithLang"`this is a reference to a property 'nameWithLang' in the vue instance. If you want just string 'nameWithLang' just use `custom-label="nameWithLang"` (note that there is no colon in the beginning).

Answer (score 0):

why not you just return the value into a variable in data, and set the function into mounted/watch instead using the function to get the value.

just for refer, you can make the script like this :

```
import AppForm from '../app-components/Form/AppForm';

Vue.component('coupon-form', {
    mixins: [AppForm],
    data: function() {
        return {
            form: {
                name:  '' ,
                description:  '' ,
                valid_from:  '' ,
                valid_till:  '' ,
                discount:  '' ,
                enabled:  false,
                books: [],
            },
            isLoading: false,
            options: [],
            selected: [],
            newName: '',
        }
    },
    methods: {
        nameWithLang({ name, sku }) {
          this.newName = `${name} — ${sku}`;
        },
        getData(query){
            this.isLoading = true;
        axios.post('/admin/books/find/'+query)
        .then((response) => {
            this.options = response.data;
            this.isLoading = false;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            this.isLoading = false;
        });
    },
},
watch: {
    selected (newValues) {
         this.form.books = newValues.map(obj => obj.id)
         this.nameWithLang();
    }
}
```

});

then you can make the template like this:

```
<multiselect v-model="selected" track-by="id" label="name" :options="options" :loading="isLoading" :internal-search="false" @search-change="getData" :multiple="true" :close-on-select="false" :hide-selected="true":internal-search="false" name="books[]" :show-labels="false" :custom-label="newName"></multiselect>
```

this is just another way you can make it and the way i'm understand what actually you want to do. you want to pass the name with lang value into the :custom-label right? so why not just defined one more variable and add the value into the variable. so you just need to pass the value instead the function. in v-bind it's more appropiate to pass a property instead of a method

Comment: I did this but it gives me this error
Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "customLabel". Expected Function, got String with value "".

Comment: can you show the child component? in the child component you should change the props type like this:

props: { customLabel: String },

it's due you set the dataType in the child file as function. you can change it to string instead of function. you should share your child file so i can help on it